# std::map with std::vector as key -- complexity of lookup function

Tags: c++, algorithm, stdvector, stdmap

I have a set of `N` customers, indexed `0,...,N-1`. Periodically, for some subset `S` of customers, I need to evaluate a function `f(S)`. Computing `f(S)` is of linear complexity in `|S|`. The set `S` of customers is represented as an object of type `std::vector<int>`. The subsets that come up for evaluation can be of different size each time. [Since the order of customers in `S` does not matter, the set can as well be represented as an object of type `std::set<int>` or `std::unordered_set<int>`.]

In the underlying application, I may have the same subset `S` of customers come up multiple times for evaluation of `f(S)`. Instead of incurring the needless linear complexity each time, I am looking to see if it would benefit from some sort of less computational burdensome lookup.

I am considering having a map of key-value pairs where the key is directly the vector of customers, `std::vector<int> S` and the value mapped to this key is `f(S)`. That way, I am hoping that I can first check to see if a key already exists in the map, and if it does, I can look it up without having to compute `f(.)` again.

Having an `std::map` with `std::vector` as keys is well-defined. See, for e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903737/stl-map-with-a-vector-for-the-key).

[CPPReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) indicates that map lookup time is logarithmic. But I suppose this is logarithmic in the number of `key`s where each key if of a constant length -- such as an `int` or a `double`, etc. How is the complexity affected where the key itself need not be of constant length and can be of arbitrary length upto size `N`?

Since the keys can themselves be of different sizes (subset of customers that come up for evaluation could be different each time), does this introduce any additional complexity in computing a hash function or the compare operation for the `std::map`? Is there any benefit to maintain the key as a binary array a fixed length `N`? This binary array is such that `B_S[i]=1` if the `i`th customer is in set `S`, and it is 0 otherwise. Does this make the lookup any easier?

I am aware that ultimately the design choice between reevaluating `f(S)` each time versus using `std::map` would have to be done based on actual profiling of my application. However, before implementing both ideas (the `std::map` route is more difficult to code in my underlying application), I would like to know if there are any known pre-existing best-practices / benchmarks.

Comment: mb you should use wrapper class, which will store vector and value of f for said vector, you will modify vector via methods of wrapper and recalculate f on modification of vector. This way you can avoid recalculations without using map

Comment: Just a remark: a vector is not a set. Order matters and a vector can contain duplicates. Unsure whether it is relevant here, but what is the reason for not using a `std::set` (or `std::unordered_set`)?

Comment: @SergeBallesta Indeed you are correct. In the underlying application, the order need not matter. I might as well go with `std::set` or `std::unordered_set` if that is going to make computations and lookups easier. I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: I would use `std::unordered_map` instead, you don't have to compare full vectors/sets each time, you can just compare hashes when doing a lookup

Comment: @coyotte508 Yes, I will consider that. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map indicates that lookup times are average constant time.

Comment: even if benchmarks exist you need to measure for your specific application. You are bascially asking if it is worh to use memoization and that depends on the cost of `f` vs lookup in the map, both depends on input size, `f` and the comparison of keys. Btw you don't need to store the whole subset as keys in the map. Subsets of a set of N elements can be enumerated with a N-bit integer (or bitset) which makes the lookup rather efficient

Comment: @Tryer: How many customers might you have? How big are the sets of customers? These are important factors in the decision about how to implement a memorization table.

Comment: Another consideration: you say that `f(S)` takes `O(|S|)`, but key comparison also takes `O(|S|)` and you must do at least one full key comparison for each lookup. I suppose that the constant factor for `f(S)` is much larger than the constant factor for comparison, but that needs to be factored in as well. If `f(S)` takes a thousand times as long as comparing `S == T`, then memorization might make sense. If it takes ten times as long, the advantage is rather more dubious. And yet another consideration: what fraction of computations can be avoided by memorization?

Comment: @rici. I am looking at around 200 for `N` and `S` can be between 10 to 25. Computing `f(S)` is a heuristic algorithm to obtain a bound of some sort on the worthiness of this customer set. I already did some profiling of my application before where I was re-calculating `f(S)` for each set that comes up and this was indeed the hotspot. Hence my search for `std::map` (or others of that nature) type memoization.

Comment: @Tryer: Ok. That's not many customers but it's still possibly enough to make a bitvector non-optimal. Suppose you represent a set of customers with a sorted sequence of `uint8_t` (possibly indexes into a vector of IDs). That's certainly adequate for 200 customers. Then the keylength for a set of 10 to 25 of them would range between 80 and 200 bits, whereas the bitvector would always be 200 bits. That comparison doesn't include the overhead of `std::vector`, which is both significant and pointless since keys are immutable; it assumes you find a more compact representation.

Comment: The storage cost of the keys could be significant if the table is large, but I was really thinking about the cost of comparison, which is related to the length of the representation. If you use `std::map`, then you also need to consider how far into the representation is the first difference. If you use `std::unordered_map`, then you need to consider the cost of hashing (linear in the representation length) as well as the comparison cost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complexity of lookup in a map is `O(log N)` That is, roughly `log N` comparisons are needed when there are `N` elements in the map. The cost of the comparison itself adds to that linearly. For example when you compare `M` vectors with `K` elements, then there are roughly `log N` comparisons, each comparing `M*K` vector elements, ie in total `O(M*K*log N)`.

However, asymptotic complexity is only that: Asymptotic complexity. When there are only a small number of elements in the map then lower order factors might outweigh the `log N` that only dominates for large `N`. Consequently, the actual runtime depends on your specific application and you need to measure to be sure.

Moreover, you shouldn't use vectors as keys in the first place. Its a waste of memory. Subsets of `S` can be enumerated with a n-bit integer when `S` has `n` elements (simply set the i-th bit when i-th element of `S` is in the subset). Comparing a single integer (or bitset) is surely more efficient than comparing vectors of integers.

Comment: The `N` in my OP need not be a const. As a result, I may be forced to use an `std::vector<bool>` instead of `std::bitset<N>`. Is there a way an optimizing compiler can work as efficiently with the former as with the latter?

Comment: I don't understand your statement "when you compare M vectors with K elements, then there are roughly log N comparisons". In the OP, `N` is the number of possible values of the elements of the vector, and it doesn't figure into the complexity if we can assume that it fits into a word. I presume that you are using `M` as the total occupancy of the table (the number of keys) and `K` as something like the average length of a single key. In that case, the lookup time is `O(K * log(M))`, but the average lookup time might be a lot less, depending on the distribution of keys.