# Using map with class error, compile error

Tags: c++, class, dictionary, compilation

I have the following compiler error, how could I fix it?

```
error:  instantiated from `_Tp& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const _Key&) [with _Key = ar, _Tp = int, _Compare = std::less<ar>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const ar, int> >]'
```

This is the code:

```
#include <map>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std; 

class ar { 
  public:
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
public:
  ar() : a(0), b(0), c(0) {}
};

int main() {
   map<ar, int> mapa;
   ar k;
   k.a = 6;
   k.b = 1;
   k.c = 0;
   mapa[k] = 1;

   //system("pause");
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: First step toward fixing your programming errors: use reasonable indentation and variable names.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573225/what-requirements-must-stdmap-key-classes-meet-to-be-valid-keys

Answer (score 1):

You need a comparison function for the `map`. You can either create `operator<` that compares two instances of `ar`, or you can create a custom function and pass it as the 3rd template parameter.

An example of the former might be:

```
class ar {
  ...
  bool operator<(const ar& rhs) const {
    return std::tie(a,b,c) < std::tie(rhs.a, rhs.b, rhs.c);
  }
  ...
};
```

Comment: why is it important to have comparison function in this case? my only wish in this case is that my class represent an index for map.

Comment: @user2085124 because the map orders it's elements in it's underlying container, and if it doesn't know **how** to order them, it can't do it.  It relies on some Comparison function being present in it's `Key` type.

Comment: i am still getting the same error. could it be another problem?

Comment: @user2085124 - There was an error in my code, which I have fixed in my answer. Notice the change in function signature to `const`. Now it [works for me](http://ideone.com/0lfuqZ).

Comment: why is it has to be const?

Comment: @user2085124 because comparing two keys should not change either of them. Otherwise the map could get seriously messed up.

Answer (score 1):

For a [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) you need to have overloaded `operator<` on the Key type of the map, because that is how the map will insert elements into it's underlying container.

```
class ar { 
  public:
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
  public:
  ar() : a(0), b(0), c(0) {}
  bool operator<(const ar& other) const;
  };

bool ar::operator< (const ar& other) const // note the function has to be const!!!
{
   return (other.a < a) && (other.b < b) && (other.c < c); // or some such ordering
}
```

When overloading `operator<`, it's a good idea to in a similar fashion also overload `operator>`.

Comment: i am still getting the same error. could it be another problem?

Comment: the `operator<` has to be `const` function. Then [it works](http://liveworkspace.org/code/X9jZV$12)

Answer (score 0):

`operator <` must be available for the key type, or you should provide a comparison functor to the map constructor.