# Can a 2D array be the key of a map?

Tags: c++, stl

I have to keep count of the occurrences of various sub matrices that occur in a matrix. Can I use a map, keeping the Key as a 2D matrix and the Value as the count? 
If I can, then what will the syntax be?

Comment: `std::map< std::vector<std::vector<int>>, int > A;`  ? Not sure why you need such DS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been addressed more generally in the following post:

[What requirements must std::map key classes meet to be valid keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573225/what-requirements-must-stdmap-key-classes-meet-to-be-valid-keys)