# Assignment operator requirement for Key type in std::map

Tags: c++, c++11, clang++

It seems to suggest here [What requirements must std::map key classes meet to be valid keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573225/what-requirements-must-stdmap-key-classes-meet-to-be-valid-keys), and in a few other posts, that the Key type of an srd::map must have an assignment operator. However I have not been able to find that requirement in the standard.

```
#include <map>

struct Foo
{
    Foo& operator=( const Foo& ) = delete;

    int id;
};

bool operator<( const Foo&, const Foo& ) { return( false ); }

int main( int, char** )
{
    std::map<Foo,int> a;
    std::map<Foo,int> b;

    a = b;   // Should this work if Foo does not have an assignment operator?

    return( false );
}
```

The above compiles with GCC 4.9 and Visual Studio 2013 but fails, complaining about the lack of an assignment operator, with clang 3.5 on an Ubuntu 14.10 box running the following command "clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ code.cpp". Clang does succeed when using the GCC standard library. I suspect the clang standard library is broken here.

Comment: ++1 I can think of little practical reason for it to be needed.  That assignment should be easily done with copy construct, for example.  Hmm.

Answer (score 4):

§23.1 [container.requirements.general]/p15 & Table 99:

> In Table 99, `X` denotes an allocator-aware container class with a
>   `value_type` of `T` using allocator of type `A`, `u` denotes a
>   variable, `a` and `b` denote non-const lvalues of type `X`, `t`
>   denotes an lvalue or a const rvalue of type `X`, `rv` denotes a
>   non-const rvalue of type `X`, and `m` is a value of type `A`.

The relevant part of Table 99 (Allocator-aware container requirements) is:

```
+-----------+-------------+--------------------------------+------------+
|Expression | Return type |   Assertion/note               | Complexity |
|           |             | pre-/post-condition            |            |
|-----------+-------------+--------------------------------+------------+
|   a = t   |      X&     | Requires: T is CopyInsertable  | linear     |
|           |             | into X and CopyAssignable.     |            |
|           |             | post: a == t                   |            |
+-----------+-------------+--------------------------------+------------+
```

And then §23.2.4 [associative.reqmts]/p7 says

> The associative containers meet all the requirements of
>   Allocator-aware containers (23.2.1), except that for `map` and
>   `multimap`, the requirements placed on `value_type` in Table 96 apply
>   instead to `key_type` and `mapped_type`. [ *Note*: For example, in some
>   cases `key_type` and `mapped_type` are required to be `CopyAssignable`
>   even though the associated `value_type`, `pair<const key_type, mapped_type>`, is not `CopyAssignable`. —*end note* ]

Note that this references Table 96, but given the note the intent is clearly to cover Table 99 as well, since nothing in Table 96 actually requires `CopyAssignable`. Since the `value_type`, `pair<const key_type, mapped_type>`, is never `CopyAssignable`, reading the Table 99 requirements to refer to it would be rather absurd.

Comment: Thanks for that, I missed the 23.2.4 bit referencing the non-associative container.

Comment: The implication of the "Note:" in 23.2.4 is that pair<const key_type,mapped_type> doesn't have to be CopyAssignable. If so this is where libc++ may be wrong as it simply assigns one pair<const key_type,mapped_type> to another. I find words like "in some cases" a bit odd, they would seem to allow different implementation to accept different code. Maybe concepts will save us all!

Comment: @goneskiing You can't assign a `pair<const something, ...>` because that element is `const`, and Table 99's requirement of CopyAssignable is on the `value_type` unless negated by 23.2.4/p7.