# Why does Linq not provide a lambda parameter instead of IEqualityComparer<T>?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

So in things like `GroupBy()` in Linq, you can provide an implementation of `IEqualityComparer<T>` to help with object comparisons.  It seems, though, that it would be easier to simply pass in a lambda expression.

Example:

```
// current implementation
myCollection.GroupBy(c => c.Foo, c => c.Bar, new FooBarComparer());

// it seems easier to...
myCollection.GroupBy(c => c.Foo, c => c.Bar, (x, y) => x.Baz == y.Baz);
```

Given a simple implementation of `IEqualityComparer<T>` like this:

```
public class FooBarComparer : IEqualityComparer<FooBar> {
    public bool Equals(FooBar x, FooBar y) {
        return x.Baz == y.Baz;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(FooBar obj) {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

It seems that providing a lambda expression could be just as effective.  As it stands now, if I try to pass in an `IEqualityComparer<T>` with a Linq query to a database, it fails because SQL Server (or whatever) doesn't know anything about my class.  It seems that a lambda would be able to be translated into SQL that can be used in the target database.

Is there a specific reason this is not provided as an option in Linq?

Comment: A lambda expression doesn't support GetHashCode, which is used internally for performance.

Comment: You'd have to have a second lambda for generating a hash code, but since determining equality and hash codes should be related it makes more sense for them to be encapsulated in the same class.

Comment: `GetHashCode()` is used in preference to `Equals()`?  I was thinking that an overload for a lambda would use that lambda for the comparison as if it were `Equals()`.

Comment: And if you want, you can directly group by `c.Foo.Baz`,

Comment: @StephenCollins How do you expect to properly compare reference types  without GetHashCode()?

Comment: @DavidL It would be done by the SQL server for example, how it becomes the SQL server problem, that surely wouldn't use a C# GetHashCode...

Comment: This question opens up the "what use are the `Queryable` method overloads that support a `IEqualityComparer<>`", like `Distinct`, `Contains`, `GroupBy`...

Comment: @xanatos That was really my thought.  I've always looked at the `IEqualityComparer<>` overloads as a good indicator NOT to use them with Linq 2 SQL statements since to me it implies that you ARE comparing equality in C#, not in SQL.

Comment: @DavidL Probably these overloads are present so that you can use "stock" comparers... For example `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`.  Then a LINQ provider could recognize a certain (fixed, small) number of them (the `StringComparer` family, for example, plus clearly the `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` that uses the default comparer)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it requires reading the minds of the developers of the feature.

Comment: Your `FooBarComparer` doesn't have a cohesive sense of identity between it's equality and it's hash code (the hash is based on the item, the equality based on one property of it), and as a result any operations using it are going to have an undefined result.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need two lambdas so that `GetHashCode` has an equivalent as well. Besides that this would work, yes. There are some LINQ methods that do not make use of hash codes but that use equality (`Enumerable.Contains`).

I guess it's just to have a standard API for equality that the whole BCL uses. You can easily convert between delegate and comparer by using a delegate-backed comparer implementation or by converting `myComparer.Equals` to a delegate.

For remoting expressions to the database is is not easy to remote a comparer expression. `GROUP BY` does not support that in SQL. It can surely be made to work but it is a niche use case (actually if the comparer expression for a `GroupBy` does not provide an equality relation I'm not sure how that would turn out when translated to SQL).

Answer (score 0):

To make an efficient `GroupBy`/`Distinct` you need two things:

- An equality comparer
- An hash generator, to create an hash dictionary

OR you can follow the C++ route

- A comparator able to order the elements, so that you are able to create a tree

If you only have an equality comparer, then the difficulty of doing the `GroupBy` is something like *O(n^2)*, because if you have 5 elements, you need 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 comparisons, so n * (n + 1) / 2 so 15. This is something a "good" library wouldn't ever permit you to do (and no sane SQL server would ever do!)

Now, clearly the LINQ library could analyze your equality lambda, see that it is

```
(x, y) => x.Baz == y.Baz
```

see that it is symmetrical, so that the left term and the right term are in the form

```
x => x.Baz
```

and use this to generate an hasher and select a comparer. But at this point, wouldn't it be easier to do directly

```
myCollection.GroupBy(c => c.Foo.Baz)
```

Yes, that you can do :-)

And then,

```
myCollection.GroupBy(c => c.Foo.Baz, c => new { c.Foo, c.Bar })
            .Select(c => new { Key = c.First().Foo, Values = c.Select(x => x.Bar) })
```

That is quite similar to your intended `GroupBy` (the only difference is that the values are in a `Values` `IEnumerable<>`)

Now... for the use of the overloads with `IEqualityComparer<T>`... as I've written in the comments, I do think that they should be used with "stock" comparers, that the LINQ provider can recognize, like the various `StringComparer.*` (e.g. `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`) and the `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`, that represents the "default" comparer.

Comment: Both C# and C++ support equality comparers and ordering comparers.  They're not specific to one language or another.  In C# this would be `IComparer` and `IEqualityComparer`.  I'm not sure what they each map to in C++, but I'm confident both exist in some form.

Comment: @Servy If you look at `map`/`multimap` of C++ you'll see that it is based on the `operator<` (or another ordering operator) (see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573225/what-requirements-must-stdmap-key-classes-meet-to-be-valid-keys). This because C++ doesn't have a "primitive" concept of hash code like C#

Comment: The fact that you've listed two non-hash based data structures doesn't mean that C++ doesn't have any hash based data structures.  That's like saying that because `SortedDictionary` isn't hash based C# doesn't use hash based data structures.  Both languages support both (even if each language makes a different one "easier").

Comment: @Servy For many years C++ didn't have the `unordered_map`. It has been introduced only in C++11. So when I say "OR you can follow the C++ route" I am right: for many many years the C++ route was "we don't have hash functions, we use comparators". In recent years it has changed to "we have both"