# in c++ std library, assigning to a map element at index -1

Tags: c++, dictionary, key, caffe

I see a code below. (it's from caffe source, a deep learning library)

```
  map<int, string> layer_idx_to_layer_name;
  layer_idx_to_layer_name[-1] = "input";
```

What does the second line mean? I guess it's assigning a default value. Is it correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's doing what it says: Assigning the string "input" to the map entry whose key is -1.

There's no concept of a default value with `std::map`.

Remember, the key of a std::map doesn't have to be an int (let alone, **positive** ints) - it can be pretty much any type. `std::map` isn't a vector.

[What requirements must std::map key classes meet to be valid keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573225/what-requirements-must-stdmap-key-classes-meet-to-be-valid-keys)

Comment: The correct term to use would be key (rather than index)

Comment: oh, I see, I forgot it -1 is actually a key value. Thanks.

Comment: and the key is of type int here(so -1 is valid). and there's no limit in the key range (no need to be continuous, no need to start from 0,..) unlike normal arrays.